# Page content loading before Navigation bar when using ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

My header loads after the page content loads almost a second later.Pushing the content down afterwards.
I want the header loading first.

**Here is the html**

```
<body ng-app="tiide" ng-cloak>

    <div ng-controller="headerController">
        <div ng-include src=header.url></div>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="header.html"></script>
    </div>

    <div>
       Hello.This is the main content of the page.
    </div>
</body>
```

**Here is my main javascript file**

```
var app = angular.module('tiide',['ngMaterial','ngAnimate','ngMessages','ngAria']);

app.controller('headerController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.header = {name: "header.html", url: "partials/header.html"};
}]);
```

**Here is the header made with Angular material**

```
<md-toolbar class="toolbar">
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <md-button aria-label="Go Back">
          Go Back
        </md-button>
        <h2>
          <span>This is the toolbar.</span>
        </h2>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-raised" aria-label="Learn More">
          Learn More
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
```

Comment: have you tried with the settimeout() function...

Comment: @learner what does it do.Does it slow the time before the page loads or what?

Comment: yes, you can set time for a particular place to load after few seconds

Comment: The setTimeout() function expects a value of milliseconds, so technically it can be less than a second (if that's what is needed in this situation).

Comment: In angular don't use setTimeout, they have a $timeout() method for that, which applies the scope for you

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for this would be to use $timeout() with no time specified (default 0), which will apply the changes at the end of the thread:

```
app.controller('headerController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.header = {name: "header.html", url: "partials/header.html"};
    });
}]);
```